how to handle pydevd.settrace() with python when forking a process
I have a question about how pydevd.settrace() works.
I am working with a python application that forks a process to handle incoming requests. This raises a question. At the beginning of the execution, in order to debug with pydev, the following are called: import pydevd; pydevd.settrace('<network address>'). I assume this sets up a network connection between the process being debugged and the debug server. Now, this application is listening on another socket (let's use linux/unix in this example) and when a request arrives, it forks a process to handle that request. What is desired is for the debugging to now involve two different independent processes - the original process and the forked process. However, (at least in unix-like OSes) both the parent and child processes share the same socket, so if a breakpoint is set for code in the parent there is no way to distinguish this from setting a breakpoint for code in the child. In other words, if the breakpoint is reached, there is no way to tell if the parent or child process triggered the breakpoint.
If the socket created by the settrace call were available, when the child process executes, it could close it and then issue a new import pydevd; pydevd.settrace call. This would separate the debugging of the parent and child But, I see no way to do that with pydevd functions (at least there is nothing in the documentation I have found on the web). Is there a way to "close" a settrace() session in order to start another?

The PyDev debugger should usually attach to all subprocesses automatically and create a new debugger session (so, what you're saying about closing a session and then starting a new one shouldn't be needed as multiple sessions can happen in parallel over the same socket server from the Eclipse side).
You may want to see whether the related setting is properly set in your installation just to make sure.

There is a caveat when using Remote Debugging though:
If you're using pydevd.settrace you need to ask it to do that though by passing patch_multiprocessing=True.
i.e.:
pydevd.settrace(host='192.168.0.1', patch_multiprocessing=True)
Another option could be just calling pydevd.settrace(...) multiple times from multiple processes -- after starting the remote debugger, any new pydevd.settrace(...) call should automatically attach to the debugger and create a new independent debug session -- just make sure you haven't stopped the remote debugger session (i.e.: in this case as in the regular case, multiple sessions can happen in parallel over the same socket server from the Eclipse side).
If the remote scenario is common for you, maybe you can leave the remote debugger always on...


Thanks for the information. The way you have setup the debug server is laudable. I assume when patch_multiprocessing=True, the debug server uses the process pid, and in the case of remote debugging, the source IP address to multiplex its sessions. Correct?

After thinking about this, I want to understand precisely what I need to do in the parent/child process situation. In the parent I execute import pydevd; pydevd.settrace(''). At some point the parent forks or uses subprocess to create the child. There is no need to call pydevd.settrace() again in the child. A new debug server session is created automatically. Or do I have this wrong? Do I need to call pydevd.settrace() again in the child, which will create the new session?

In the previous comment, I should have said, "I execute import pydevd; pydevd.settrace('', patch_multiprocessing=True)". I tried to edit the comment, but there is a time limit of 5 minutes after which the comment is not editable. The clarification about having to call settrace again stems from my lack of understanding how debug sessions are created. If the parent and child are on a different machine than the debug server, I don't see how it can know that a child process is created and thereby create a new session for it.

Again, giving the situation more thought. How does the remote debugger know that a remote process terminates and consequently destroys the debug session? I am using the term debug session to represent the entry in the debug sidebar associated with the process that terminates.

When the connection is broken the remote debugger finishes the related debug session. There's some patching that happens in the python side before launching a new process to automatically call pydevd.settrace in the new process and then call your own command, the point being that pydevd.settrace is the thing that makes the connection and you could just call it manually again in the subprocess.

OK. Thanks. I am in the process of attempting to use Eclipse/PyDev to walk through the code using the debugger. I have run into a problem, which is described in a different Stack Overflow thread (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79029217/eclipse-cant-execute-python-script-from-particular-directory). I still don't understand how Eclipse/PyDev will know when a remote child subprocess exits in order to close down the debug session assigned to it, since both the parent and child use the same socket to communicate to the debug server. But, getting debugging to work will help with that.
