PyDev can't execute python script from particular directory
I am using Eclipse with PyDev to develop an understanding of a particular application (Salt) written in Python. I clone the application from GitHub and then create a project in Eclipse in order to use the debugger to see how it works. The problem is, I select one of the Python scripts and attempt to set a breakpoint. However, Eclipse/PyDev won't allow me to do so (instead, when I double click to the left of the statement, it gives me the option to add a bookmark). Here is an image that shows the file in Eclipse:

Notice that the file is actually a shell script that calls python. However, the shebang (i.e., #!) is just a comment to python, so that shouldn't confuse Eclipse. The rest of the text is python code.
I noticed that none of the files in the scripts directory had a .py suffix. So, I copied salt-minion to both salt-minion.py and salt-minion-py.py. I then restarted Eclipse. As you can see from the next image, these files exist in the scripts directory. However, they do not show up in the Eclipse listing of that directory.

So, my questions is: How do I get Eclipse/PyDev to recognize these files so I can set breakpoints and then execute them using the debugger?
Just so everything is clear, here is a screenshot showing the scripts directory.

Added later: One thing I should mention, since it may have something to do with why salt-minion.py and salt-minion-py.py do not show up, is the directories under "Source" were added by New->Other->PyDev->Link to existing source. I don't know if that is a static addition, meaning files in the existing source that were added after the "Link to existing source" operation do not appear. I was assuming Link to existing source had the same semantics as a soft link in Linux, but that may be a bad assumption.

When you right-click one of these files and choose in the Open With menu the Python editor, do you get then syntax highlighting?

Linking in the IDE is similar to soft links in the filesystem. You might need to File|Refresh on the parent folder so see externally added files.

@howlger Thanks. right-clicking and choosing  'Open With' menu in the Python Editor did indeed fix the problem. I am now able to place a breakpoint in the Python code.

@nitind Also, thank you for your suggestion. File|Refresh on the parent folder did update the additional files.

The problem was solved by @howlger and @nitind. Right clicking and choosing the 'Open With' menu in the Python editor fixed the problem with Eclipse not recognizing the shebang script as Python code. After doing so, I was able to set breakpoints and the editor used Python code highlighting.
Selecting the parent folder and selecting File|Refresh updated the scripts directory shown in the project explorer pane, so that both added files appeared.

The "Workspace" preference page has an option for it to do so automatically. It's a small performance hit on supported platforms, so off by default.

Thanks. I will look into that.
